# Asus Eee Pc 1005PX Keyboard Issue

Tags: drivers, 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, eeepc

my wife gave me her laptop to fix it. There was a ugly windows 7 starter on it. I decided to drop the windows into junk and use Ubuntu Distro 18.04.

There were some hooks to get startet with the sound and fn-key finaly I thought everything would work fine. But actually I get a issue with keyboard.

Three keys are not working propper(sometimes yes, but mostly no). The ESC-, ARROWUP- and ARROWDOWNKEY. I already checked xev there are no intereupts generated when the issue comes to time.
Does anybody has a idea where this might come from?
Actually I spend a big load of time to get this working clearly.

Thanks for careing.